# Matlab: Randomly select from "slowly varying" index set

Tags: matlab, data-structures

I would like to find or implement a Matlab data structure that allows me to efficiently do the following three things:

- Retrieve an element uniformly at random.
- Add a new element.
- Delete an element. (If it helps, this element was just "retrieved" out of the structure, so I can use both its location and its value to delete it).

Since I don't need duplicates, this structure is mathematically equivalent to a set. Also, my elements are always integers in the range 1 to 2500; it is not unusual for the set to be this entire range.

What is such a data structure? I've thought of using something like containers.Map or java.util.HashSet, but I don't know how to satisfy the first requirement in this case, because I don't know how to efficiently retrieve the nth key of such a structure. An ordinary array can achieve the first requirement of course, but it is a bad choice for the second and third requirements because of inefficient resizing.

For some context for why I'm looking to do this, in some current code I spent about 1/4 of the runtime doing:

```
find(x>0,Inf)
```

and then randomly retrieving an element from this vector. Yet this vector changes very little, and in a very predictable manner, in each iteration of my program. So I would prefer to carry around a data structure and update it as I go rather than recomputing it every time.

If you're familiar with Haskell, one way to implement the operations I'm looking to support would be

```
randomSelect set = fmap (\n -> elemAt n set) $ randomRIO (0,size set-1)
```

along with `insert` and `delete`, from [Data.Set](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.8.1/docs/Data-Set.html). But I have other reasons not to use Haskell in this project, and I don't know how to implement the backend of Data.Set myself.

Comment: Is the order of the elements important? Do you always select the elements randomly? Do you have to check for duplication when inserting an element?

Comment: @beaker The order does not matter. Retrieval is always random. I need to *prevent* duplication, and it would be convenient for the structure to do this for me, but I can do that a different way if necessary.

Comment: Great, this is what I needed to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frequently, the best way to decrease time complexity is to increase space complexity. Given that your sets are going to be rather small, we can probably afford to use a little extra space.

To contain the set itself, you can use a preallocated array:

```
maxSize = 2500;
theSet = zeros(1, maxSize);    % set elements
setCount = 0;                  % number of set elements
```

You can then have an auxiliary array to check for set membership:

```
isMember = zeros(1, maxSize);
```

To insert a new element `newval` into the set, add it to the end of `theSet` and increment the count (assuming there's room):

```
if ~isMember(newval)
   assert(setCount < maxSize, 'Too many elements in set.');
   theSet(++setCount) = newval;
   isMember(newval) = 1;
else
   % tried to add duplicate element... do something here
end
```

To delete an element by index `delidx`, swap the element to be deleted and the last element and decrement the count:

```
assert(delidx <= setCount, 'Tried to remove element beyond end of set.');
isMember(theSet(delidx)) = 0;
theSet(delidx) = theSet(setCount--);
```

Getting a random element of the set is then simple, just:

```
randidx = randi(setCount);
randelem = theSet(randidx);
```

All operations are `O(1)` and the only real disadvantage is that we have to carry along two arrays of size `maxCount`. Because of that you probably don't want to put these operations in functions as you'd end up creating new arrays on every function call. You'd be better off putting them inline or, better yet, wrapping them in a nice class.

Comment: That's clever, using a counter to turn an array into a partition. It reminds me a bit of zippers in functional programming. Thanks a lot!